# is it possible to await for a promise response using setInterval?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Basically i have an timer, lets say the timer starts at 60 seconds and goes to 0 when it reaches 0 it makes an api call and the timer restarts, the issue im having is that when the timer reaches 0 it just restars without awaiting for the promise response, in someway i need for the timer to pause at 0 wait for the response and then start counting from 60 again, i tried using `clearInterval()` but it works only in the 1st countdown after it the timer just stops, here is my following code, i think it will be easier to understand

```js
setInterval(async () => {
    document.querySelector('.timeh1').innerHTML = newInterval - i
    i++
    if(i >= newInterval){
        await apiCallReload(currency)                
        i = 0
    }
    }, 1000)
```

as you can see this function is executed each second and when the running time (i) reaches the timer limit (newInterval) it will call my `apiCallReload()` function and the timer will reset to 0 again, but the problem is that the timer resets without awaiting for the function promise ( it takes between 5 - 10 seconds to get the response from the api) is there an way/workaround that i can make the timer stops when it reaches 0, wait for the api response and then start counting again?

Comment: Use `setTimeout` instead and call that when the promise is resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you have to use setTimeout(), smth like this

```
let time = 60;

async function callback() {
  time = time - 1;
  if (time === 0) {
   await fetch('https://google.com');
   time = 60;
  }
  setTimeout(callback, 1000)
}

callback()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve the desired result using a while loop...

```js
let waitTime = 3000

;(async ()=>{
  console.log('Started')
  while(true) {
      await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(res,waitTime))
      console.log('Waited', waitTime, 'ms')
      let randTime = 1000 + Math.random()*1000
      await new Promise(res=>setTimeout(()=>{console.log('your asnyc fun',randTime);res();},randTime)) //  your async func
  }
})()
```